# Why can't I shoot a bow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On Minecraft (PC), I am unable to shoot any bows by holding Right-Click. I can still activate buttons and other things, yet it just won't work with Bows!

I am able to do it sometimes, but now on 1.8.9, it fails. Is it me, or the clientside server? What could cause this?

Comment: Stupid question: do you have any arrows?

Comment: @Unionhawk After so many hours, safe to say you guessed right.

Answer (score 2):

The server had bows off in that game mode. You're not supposed to get or use any but I got one by lucky drop.

Answer (score -1):

I would assume it is on the clientside, I have tested a bow on 1.8.9 and it works perfectly fine for me. Try on a single player world to determine if it is you though.